# Understanding how to make React website mobile friendly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been playing around with [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) to understand how to make websites mobile-friendly. Essentially, what I want to do is pass in a value from a function that tests whether a viewing screen is sized like a mobile phone. Practically stolen from the documentation of react-responsive, I have a function in a file called Mobile.js as follows:

```
const Mobile = () => {
  const mobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 1000px)' })
  return (
    <div>
      {mobile && <p>You are sized like a mobile phone</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, what I want to be able to do is pass the boolean "mobile" into other classes in other js files where I can then use different CSS classNames depending on the value of this boolean.

**I have 3 specific questions.**

1. How would I return the boolean mobile from the Mobile function to be used?
2. How would I access this returned boolean?
3. How would I change the className of a div depending on the value of this boolean?

**Pretty new to web development (especially React) and these questions seem super simple and easy to solve, but for some reason, I just can't seem to figure it out by my own online research. Would love direct help and also some resources where I could learn more. Thank you so much!**

To me, in a perfect world, the right code would look like this in my mind. Not sure how far off I am, but I was hoping maybe this could be of some guidance as to how I'm thinking.

In the function file,

```
// FILE Mobile.js
const Mobile = () => {
  const mobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 1000px)' })
  return (
    { mobile } // how to return a value?
  );
}

export default Mobile;
```

In another file,

```
// FILE OtherClass.js
import Mobile from './Mobile';
class OtherClass extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { mobile: <Mobile /> } // how to access the returned value?
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.mobile && <div className="text-mobile">} // how to change the className depending on value?
        {!this.state.mobile && <div className="text-desktop">}
          blah blah blah blah blah
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding but I think if I were to implement it according to the 3 questions you have it would be something like that:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  // the point of using hooks is to use it whenever you need it (you "hook it")
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 1000px)' });
  const textStyle = isMobile ? 'text-mobile' : 'text-desktop';

  return (
    <div className={textStyle}>
    enter code here
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps :)

---

**Edit**

To reuse this logic you can do a wrapper div component instead:

```
const MyWrapperComponent = (props) => {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 1000px)' });
  const textStyle = isMobile ? 'text-mobile' : 'text-desktop';

  return (
    <div className={textStyle}>
     {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

// Then you can use it like so:

const HomePage = () => (
   <MyWrapperComponent>
     write the rest of the code here
   </MyWrapperComponent>
)
```

Children are a kind of props that are native to react, quite basically just means they are whatever you provide between the tags of the component that's receiving them :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was so straightforward and helpful. Quick question, is there a way such that I don't have to copy and paste the hook code in every file?

Comment: You can use an higher order component that applies that. Assuming you always have the same div behaviour. You can also do something like a wrapper component. I'll edit my answer to include it :)

Comment: Using context hooks should be prefered in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for asking and welcome to React development !

Here how I can help you

> How would I return the boolean mobile from the Mobile function to be
>   used?
>
> How would I access this returned boolean?

Since you are calling a hook `useMediaQuery`, you need also a hook to reuse it and returns its value :

```
function useIsMobile() {
   const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 1000px)' });
   return isMobile
}
//Then you can share this logic in other components
function Component1(){
   const isMobile = useIsMobile()
   ...
}
function Component2(){
   const isMobile = useIsMobile()
   ...
}
```

Please note that you can't use hooks inside `class` components.

> How would I change the className of a div depending on the value of
>   this boolean?

This is straightforward:

```
function Component(){
   const isMobile = useIsMobile()
   const className = isMobile ? 'mobile-class' : 'desktop-class'
   return <div className={className}>...</div>
}
```

If you need more complex className logic you can checkout [the package classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) which makes it very easy to activate/deactivate classes.